# Paypal Transaction Search end_date filter not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been using paypal for several months and I have not encountered any problems.

But I can not get the latest transactions  using [PayPal Transaction Search api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1)

It does not return the orders starting from Mar 7,2020.
There is no error message. Actually There is no error.

My request url is

> https://api.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2020-02-29T11:00:00Z&end_date=2020-03-09T23:59:00Z&page_size=200&page=1

And its response is like

> {"transaction_details":[],"account_number":"***","start_date":"2020-02-29T01:00:00+0000","end_date":"2020-03-07T07:29:59+0000","last_refreshed_datetime":"2020-03-07T07:29:59+0000","page":1,"total_items":0,"total_pages":0,"links":[{"href":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/reporting/transactions?start_date=2020-02-29T01%3A00%3A00Z&end_date=2020-03-09T23%3A59%3A00Z&fields=all&page_size=200&page=1","rel":"self","method":"GET"}]}

Although my end_date parameter is 2020-03-09 , it says end_date is 2020-03-07T07:29:59+0000 in the response

My account is under review for a specific reason.

Can it be related to this process?

Thanks